# Which of the following integral domains are Euclidean domains

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following integral domains are Euclidean domains?

1. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$
2. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$
3. $\mathbb{R}[x^2,x^3]=\{f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\in\mathbb{R}[x]:a_1=0\}$
4. $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x))[y]$

How can we solve this problem. Can anyone suggest me something. Thanks

Comment: To show that something is a ED, find a Euclidean function. To show thta something isn't, e.g show that it's not a PID.

Comment: @priti: Something is very strange in you definition of (3)

Comment: @AlexB., ok if it works, but there are PIDs that are not Euclidean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain#Properties

Answer (score 7):

Note that every ED is PID and every PID is UFD. Now comming to your question,

- $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}i]$ is not UFD because $(1+\sqrt{3}i)(1-\sqrt{3}i)=4=2.2$
- $\mathbb{Z}[x] $ is not PID because $(2,x)$ is not principal.
- Note that $x^2$ and $x^3$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x^2,x^3]$ and $(x^2)^3=x^6=(x^3)^2,$ hence it is not a UFD.
- $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x)\cong\mathbb{F}_2$ which is a field, hence $\mathbb{F}_2[y]$ is ED.

Hence the correct option is the $4$th one.